# Degree of a single extension of a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be a field.
Let $L:=K(b)$ where $b^m\in K$ but $b^i\not\in K$ for all $0<i<m$.

Then is $[L:K]=m$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example, $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q}$ has degree $\phi(n)$, but we usually don't have $\zeta_n^{\phi(n)} \in \mathbb{Q}$. For example, when $n=3$, then $\phi(n)=2$, $\zeta_3 = \frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ and $\zeta_3^2 = \frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}$.

Comment: Why is this question on hold ? Its perfectly good, and much better than other questions...

Comment: This question comes from Neukirch's book ANT p156 line 16(We may assume that...). The fact might be wrong or I am blind for additional assumption. . But I understood the entire proof of the theorem, with minor change avoiding this fact.

Comment: In above, line 16 means line 16-18.